# How to check how much the first row is hidden in UITableView without using contentOffset?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to know how much of first cell is hidden for current scroll in `UITableView`. In other words, at what point in cell's coordinates, that cell is not covered yet?

The `contentOffset` cannot be used because I will calculate it by myself.

Comment: Why can't the content offset be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get `indexPath` for first visible row, and then convert its origin to cell's coordinates:

```
if let firstVisibleIndexPath = indexPathsForVisibleRows?.first {

    if let cell = cellForRowAtIndexPath(firstVisibleIndexPath) {
        let coveredHeightOfFirstVisibleCell = tableView.superview!.convertPoint(tableView.frame.origin, toView: cell).y
    }
}
```